# How to print function call timeline?

Tags: rust

I would like to print location and function name of each function during a run.

It would help during debug to identify which function is called when multiple functions have the same name in different places.

It is possible but time costly to add by hand message such as:

`println!("(function_name) file = {}, line = {}",file!(),line!());`

Do you know such a solution? Have you suggestions to identify easily which function is called and who calls it?

Comment: use log crate + something like simpler pretty log crate

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would probably be to use something like dtrace or ebpf: hook onto the "function entry" probe (not sure what it's called in linux / ebpf land but I'd think it exists) and just print the relevant information. You may want to add stack-based indentation though, and of course because of compiler optimisations you might have functions going missing. And you might get the mangled names which is not great, but de-mangling is a thing.

You might be able to do something similar by running your program in gdb and creating some sort of programmatic breakpoints which print and immediately continue?

Alternatively, a module-level attribute procedural macro could work: if you get a token stream for the entire module, it might be possible to automatically inject logging data into every function header.